# Applying for jobs in Singapore without Employment Pass?

Tags: working-visas, singapore

I'm an Australian citizen looking to work in Singapore. I believe I would meet the requirements for an Employment Pass.

According to the self assessment tool I met the criteria.

I've noticed some advertised positions specifically mention visa sponsorship.

If a position does not mention sponsorship, is it worth applying? I do not technically have the right to work in Singapore.  Is it a usual process for HR departments to assist with obtaining an Employment Pass?

Comment: If you have hard-to-find skills then it could be worth applying; however companies are also restricted in the amount of work pass holders that they can employ based on the number of citizens/PR holders that they employ. So whether the company could get an EP for you if they were interested in you, depends on this.

Comment: Note that if you can't get an Employment Pass for some reason, you would probably still be able to get an [S-Pass](http://www.mom.gov.sg/passes-and-permits/s-pass), for which however there's foreigner quotas. Either way you would have to get a job first and your employer will then have to apply for you. Employers generally know the requirements for hiring foreigners. In my experience of looking for a job in Singapore (I'm currently on a S-Pass), employers who are not willing to hire foreigners will either state so in the ad (as @jpatokal mentioned) or not reply to your application.

Comment: @WW. I believe the industry will be an important factor here. What kind of job is this?

Comment: @pacerier Fintech, so a bank, financial start-up, payment processor etc

Answer (score 6):

Singapore is a small country with lots of foreigners working in all sorts of jobs.  As a rule, for professional roles, *unless* the job posting states "Singaporeans & PRs only" (and many do), it's worth at least enquiring whether they will sponsor an Employment Pass.

That said, Singapore has ratcheted up [the requirements for getting an EP considerably over the last few years](http://www.mom.gov.sg/passes-and-permits/employment-pass/eligibility), and unless you're at the very top of the income bracket (fixed monthly salary S$12,000+), getting a pass is no longer guaranteed.  So you will still be at a disadvantage when applying for any job if you are competing against locals.

Comment: You gave some good help (+1). Just a pity that the OP does not want to help others in turn and accept this as the answer, which would help others reading this question in future.